Function in a query does not return more than one row when reading from another record in a table
I have a basic function that when given one number as input can return two different values in the form of a table. I would like this function to read the values contained in a column of another table, but I am not succeeding at this.
If the function returns a string it works without problem, but I would like the function to be able to give me an output of one column and two rows based on one record value of a different table.
I provide some basic code to explain exactly what I am trying to achieve:
-- Creation mapping_table_test

create or replace TABLE mapping_table_test (
    status VARCHAR(100),
    operator VARCHAR(100),
    num1 NUMBER(38, 0),
    num2 NUMBER(38, 0)
);

-- Insert values

insert into mapping_table_test  (status, operator, num1) 
values ('Overdue', '=', 10);
insert into mapping_table_test  (status, operator, num1, num2) 
values ('On-hold', 'B', 9, 11);

-- Function creation
-- The function reads from the previous table

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map_value_basic (field_value STRING)
RETURNS TABLE(status STRING)
AS
$$
  SELECT 
    status
  FROM mapping_table_test 
  WHERE 
         (operator = '=' AND field_value = num1) OR
         (operator = 'B' AND field_value between num1 AND num2)
$$;

-- Testing the function

SELECT * FROM table(map_value_basic('10')); -- Returns: Overdue, on-hold

-- Creating another table the function reads from 
create or replace TABLE tbl_to_map_basic (
    value_num NUMBER(38, 0)
);

-- Inserting values

insert into tbl_to_map_basic (value_num) 
values (10);

SELECT * FROM tbl_to_map_basic;

-- Function bridging the two tables

SELECT * FROM table(map_value_basic('SELECT * FROM tbl_to_map_basic'));


This last SELECT is not working ('Numeric value 'SELECT * FROM tbl_to_map_basic' is not recognized', it is expecting a number).
I found a quite long solution based on the function returning a string (not a table) with comma-separated values that I can then separate in different columns and unpile again within the same column. However, I would need a more direct approach.
What I am expecting is a table such as SELECT * FROM table(map_value_basic('10'));, which returns two rows with values 'Overdue' and 'On-hold'. I only want to be able to provide the other table as input, also assuming that in a more complex scenario sometimes the number will only return one value, not two necessarily.

Hi - it's not clear, to me, what you are actually trying to do - but if you want to pass a SQL string into your function and use it as SQL then you will need code in your function to execute it. If you just want to pass a table name into your function then you would need to construct a SQL statement within your function that uses the table name and then execute that SQL. In both cases you may also need to further process the resultset from the queries to return the data structure that you need

Hi! When I pass it as a string it actually works with no problem. For that I created a different function that takes this function and then returns the two rows within one string. The problem is that I need the output in a way that I can use the values from a column as input and if it returns two values, the it simply duplicates the row for each of them. Let´s say that column "value_num" is 10 in one row and 9 in another. Then the output of the function would be a column with values "Overdue", "On-hold", "On-hold" (three rows, not two)

You're trying to use the output of one query SELECT * FROM tbl_to_map_basic as the input to a table function table(map_value_basic(...)). The way to do this in Snowflake is with a CROSS JOIN.
The simplest way to write a CROSS JOIN is with a comma-separated list of your data sources in the FROM statement, as so:
WITH my_values AS (
  SELECT value_num
  FROM tbl_to_map_basic
)

SELECT *
FROM my_values,
     table(map_value_basic(TO_VARCHAR(value_num)))
;

This returns:
| VALUE_NUM | STATUS   |
|-----------|----------|
| 10        | Overdue  |
| 10        | On-hold  |


This put me in the good direction to what I want to achieve, thanks!

i tried this and was able to make it work, you were giving your query as a string, you just pass the query without quotes.
SELECT * FROM table(map_value_basic(SELECT value_num  FROM tbl_to_map_basic));



You are completely right with this. I can see that this work with my example, but not I a more complex scenario where I have more than one row in the tbl_to_map_basic, unfortunately... I get this error: "Single-row subquery returns more than one row."
